# Graph Theory Math Olympiad Problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> A simple graph with $n$ vertices and more than $\frac{3(n-1)}2$ edges is given. Prove that two different vertices $x$, $y$ of $G$ can be found, such that there exist $3$ non-intersecting each other paths connecting $x$ and $y$.

---

Two paths connecting $x$ and $y$ are non-intersecting if they do not share a vertex different from $x$ and $y$.
Simple means no loops or multiple edges between vertices

Not sure about how to solve this problem. I tried to use induction.

Comment: Please show us what your attempt with induction was.

Comment: What is this....a problem statement for ants??

Comment: Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of contradiction, let us assume that no such pair of vertices $x,y$ exist.

We can assume that the graph is connected,because if it were not, it must have a component satisfying the problem conditions, since otherwise the sum of edges will atmost  $\sum 3(a_i-1)/2<3(n-1)/2$ edges.(where $a_i$ are the number of vertices in each component)
Now, since the number of vertices is greater than $n-1$, there must exist a cycle.

Now, in that cycle, no two vertices of this cycle can be connected to each other other than through the cycle.
If there are $m$ vertices in the cycle, then, after delecting m edges of the cycle, we get $m$ different components. One of these components must satisfy the conditions on the number of edges, because if it did not, the total number of edges will be atmost $\sum 3(b_i-1)/2 \leq 3(n)/2 -3m/2$, (where $b_i$ is the number in each of these components) which on adding the original $m$ edges gives $3n/2-m/2 <3(n-1)/2$. Now we are done by induction.